# Showing a function is bounded

Tags: real-analysis

Please why if you have a function in $BV$ then $F$ is a bounded function.

where $BV$ = { $F$: $R$  $\to$  $C$  , T$_F$($\infty$) < $\infty$ }

Comment: What do you know and what have you tried?

Comment: I know that the Total variation is increasing because if a < b then   
 $$T_F(b)- T_F(a) = \sup\{ \sum_{j=1}^n | F(x_j)-F(x_{j-1})|:  a= x_0< ... < x_n = b ,  n \in\mathbb{N} \}$$      is positive

Comment: Any help please ?

Answer (score 0):

$|F(b)-F(a)| \leq T_F (b) -T_F (a)$ by definition, so F is bounded.

Comment: How to show that | F(b) - F(a) | < T$_F$(b) - T$_F$(a) ? Thanks

Comment: $\{a,b\}$ is itself a partition!